# Switch to manifest V3: service worker does not allow functions from content scripts anymore

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm currently developing a chrome extension, [and all worked well with the manifest V2](https://github.com/MarcBrillault/alt-to-title-chrome-extension/releases/tag/manifestv2).

I'm trying to switch to manifest V3, and I have an issue.

The extention provides a context menu element for a specific domain (Twitter).
When this element is clicked, some alterations should be done on the page (Toggling CSS classes for specific elements, in order to hide the user's name & avatar before taking a screenshot of the conversation).

In the version 2 of the manifest, I had this line of code, in the `background.js` file:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { code: "triggerMasks()" });
```

With the triggerMasks() function being on my second JS file, loaded in the `content_scripts`.

In version 3, `chrome.tabs` has apparently been replaced with `chrome.scripts`. I added the `scripting` permission to the manifest and adapted my code, but my function is not recognized anymore. It seems the new method only allows functions from the service worker to be loaded.

```
chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: tab.id },
    function: triggerMasks // Error in event handler: ReferenceError: triggerMasks is not defined
});
```

My current work is available here : https://github.com/MarcBrillault/twitter-anonymizer/tree/manifest-v3

What am I doing wrong ? How could I call the `content_scripts` method from the context menu ?

Comment: The correct usage is `func: () => triggerMasks()`

Comment: @wOxxOm could you make your comment as an answer so I validate it ?

Answer (score 1):

Alternate approach: if the code is already loaded in the content script, it would make more sense to pass a message to the content script to trigger it.

So, add a `chrome.runtime.onMessage` listener to the content script code, and use `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` to [pass a command to trigger your code](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/#simple).

If you're determined to use `scripting.executeScript`, I believe you can inject a file with `triggerMasks()` in it (if the code you want to execute is static), but the messaging to trigger a well-known action is a cleaner approach.

Comment: Thank you, it seems to be exactly what I'm looking for, I'll try this evening !